# Is there any xml-include-like thing for Java class?

Tags: android

When we make Android layout in XML, we can use `include` to make some other layout the part of the host layout. Is there such thing for Java class?

I am attaching a top bar layout to every screen and it contains buttons. Now in every Java class I have to copy/paste the initialization code.

Is there any shortcut for such scenarios? Can `Application` class facilitate anyhow? If anyone has a working solution, please share it with me.

For example, in XML I can use

```
//...xml layout elements
<include layout="@layout/topbar" />
//...some other xml layouts
```

so it would be cool to be able to use in Java code something where I could instantly initiate buttons, register `onClick` events and set actions to these events. It all the same piece of code I am using, after all.

Comment: Such things are common in browser-based UI utilities like Tiles and SiteMesh.  Don't know about Android.

Comment: It's called a base class or utility method.

Comment: @DaveNewton You mean a simple utility class to which I pass a `Context` (beside other parameters) and it'll do the rest? No need for global things like `Application` class?

Comment: @DaveNewton It works. I passed `Activity` and been able to do the stuff I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an activity (BaseActivity) with the implementation you desire and just extend this class in your other activities.

Comment: Thanks. I can do like this or via utility class passing it `Activity`. Both way works. Thanks